# Azure Databricks generates error: ParquetDecodingException: could not verify page integrity, CRC checksum verification failed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

While running the following query in SparkSQL (Ignore the column names, the query does not have any syntax error):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE db.tbl1 AS
select a.*,ifnull(b.col2,0) AS col2,b.col3 AS pre_col3,b.col4 AS pre_col4,b.col5 AS pre_col5,b.col6 AS pre_col6

FROM db.tbl1 a
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT bcol1,bcol2,1 AS bflag,CONCAT(bcol3,"-",bcol4) AS pre_bcol5,bcol5,bcol6,bcol7

FROM db.tbl2

WHERE column_name='ABC') b
ON a.acol1=b.bcol1 AND a.acol9=b.bcol9
```

### I face the following error:

---

Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 76 in stage 780.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 76.3 in stage 780.0 (TID 3815) (10.5.4.29 executor 6): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file abfss:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/database/database/table/part-00040-4d085581-b8f9-4ecd-a768-2d47ca48d3fb-c000.snappy.parquet.
**ParquetDecodingException: could not verify page integrity, CRC checksum verification failed**

Detailed Error:

```
Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Job aborted.

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:342)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWriteEdge.$anonfun$writeFiles$1(TransactionalWriteEdge.scala:564)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.withOperationTypeTag(DeltaLogging.scala:193)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.withOperationTypeTag$(DeltaLogging.scala:180)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.withOperationTypeTag(OptimisticTransaction.scala:112)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperationInternal$2(DeltaLogging.scala:157)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile(DeltaLogging.scala:262)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile$(DeltaLogging.scala:260)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperationInternal$1(DeltaLogging.scala:156)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$1(UsageLogging.scala:546)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:641)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:662)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:403)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:147)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:401)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:398)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:22)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:446)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:22)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:636)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:555)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:22)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:546)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:516)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:22)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:144)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:72)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:59)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:103)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:433)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:412)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.recordOperation(OptimisticTransaction.scala:112)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperationInternal(DeltaLogging.scala:155)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:145)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:133)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.recordDeltaOperation(OptimisticTransaction.scala:112)

    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile(DeltaLogging.scala:262)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile$(DeltaLogging.scala:260)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.recordFrameProfile(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:55)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperationInternal$1(DeltaLogging.scala:156)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$1(UsageLogging.scala:546)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:641)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:662)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:403)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:147)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:401)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:398)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:22)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:446)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:22)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:636)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:555)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:22)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:546)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:516)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:22)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:144)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:72)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:59)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:103)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:433)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:412)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.recordOperation(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:55)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperationInternal(DeltaLogging.scala:155)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:145)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:133)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.recordDeltaOperation(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:55)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.run(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:120)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaCatalog.com$databricks$sql$transaction$tahoe$catalog$DeltaCatalog$$createDeltaTable(DeltaCatalog.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaCatalog$StagedDeltaTableV2.commitStagedChanges(DeltaCatalog.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.$anonfun$writeToTable$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:520)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1731)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.writeToTable(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:501)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.writeToTable$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AtomicReplaceTableAsSelectExec.writeToTable(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AtomicReplaceTableAsSelectExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(QueryExecution.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$withMVTagsIfNecessary(QueryExecution.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:820)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:815)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:695)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.$anonfun$executeSql$1(SQLDriverLocal.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:37)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:145)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$24(DriverLocal.scala:740)
    at com.databricks.unity.EmptyHandle$.runWith(UCSHandle.scala:124)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$21(DriverLocal.scala:723)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:403)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:147)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:401)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:398)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:446)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:700)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:622)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:614)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommandAndGetError(DriverWrapper.scala:533)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:568)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:438)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:381)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:232)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 76 in stage 780.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 76.3 in stage 780.0 (TID 3815) (10.5.4.29 executor 6): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file abfss:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/database/database/table/part-00040-4d085581-b8f9-4ecd-a768-2d47ca48d3fb-c000.snappy.parquet.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:623)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1(FileScanRDD.scala:456)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:451)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:1983)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:761)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$4(Task.scala:137)
    at com.databricks.unity.EmptyHandle$.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:137)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1697)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:905)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: could not verify page integrity, CRC checksum verification failed
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$Chunk.verifyCrc(ParquetFileReader.java:1471)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$Chunk.readAllPages(ParquetFileReader.java:1539)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$Chunk.readAllPages(ParquetFileReader.java:1480)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readChunkPages(ParquetFileReader.java:1101)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:995)
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.CachingParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(CachingParquetFileReader.java:306)
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.CachingParquetFileReader.readNextFilteredRowGroup(CachingParquetFileReader.java:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase$ParquetRowGroupReaderImpl.readNextRowGroup(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:558)
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.DatabricksVectorizedParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(DatabricksVectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:681)
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.DatabricksVectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(DatabricksVectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:557)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:575)
    ... 35 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3376)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3308)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3299)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3299)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1428)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1428)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1428)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3588)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3526)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3514)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:51)
Caused by: com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file abfss:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/database/database/table/part-00040-4d085581-b8f9-4ecd-a768-2d47ca48d3fb-c000.snappy.parquet.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:623)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1(FileScanRDD.scala:456)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:451)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:1983)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:761)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$4(Task.scala:137)
    at com.databricks.unity.EmptyHandle$.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:137)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1697)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:905)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: could not verify page integrity, CRC checksum verification failed
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$Chunk.verifyCrc(ParquetFileReader.java:1471)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$Chunk.readAllPages(ParquetFileReader.java:1539)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$Chunk.readAllPages(ParquetFileReader.java:1480)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readChunkPages(ParquetFileReader.java:1101)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:995)
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.CachingParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(CachingParquetFileReader.java:306)
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.CachingParquetFileReader.readNextFilteredRowGroup(CachingParquetFileReader.java:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase$ParquetRowGroupReaderImpl.readNextRowGroup(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:558)
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.DatabricksVectorizedParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(DatabricksVectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:681)
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.DatabricksVectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(DatabricksVectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:557)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:575)
    ... 35 more

    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:130)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:145)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$24(DriverLocal.scala:740)
    at com.databricks.unity.EmptyHandle$.runWith(UCSHandle.scala:124)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$21(DriverLocal.scala:723)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:403)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:147)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:401)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:398)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:446)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:700)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:622)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:614)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommandAndGetError(DriverWrapper.scala:533)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:568)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:438)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:381)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:232)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

---

Any help on getting this resolved would be really appreciated.

Comment: well the error `ParquetDecodingException: could not verify page integrity, CRC checksum verification failed` indicates that there was an error during the creation/writing of the file. Essentially, that means that your file is invalid since the CRC validation didn't succeed

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided indicates that there is a CRC checksum verification failure while reading a Parquet file from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 (ADLS Gen2). This could be caused by data corruption or other issues in the Parquet file.

Verify the data in both the source and target tables to ensure there is no corrupted data.
After writing the tables data to the ADLS I have deleted the PARQUET files from ADLS
Thats when I received the below Error
[image]

In your Case the issue could be because of the file corrupted with. please check you parquet file while you are writing data to ADLS and while reading the file.

I have reproduced to read data from the **ADLS(Parquet)** and  performing a **LEFT JOIN** and selecting specific columns with certain aliases.

I tried to reproduce it in pyspark the below is the code:

```
output_path_t1 = "abfss://folder1@storagejuly26.dfs.core.windows.net/CRC/t1.parquet"
output_path_t2 = "abfss://folder1@storagejuly26.dfs.core.windows.net/CRC/t2.parquet"
df_t1.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(output_path_t1)
df_t2.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(output_path_t2)
result_table_01 = df_t1.alias("a").join(
df_t2.alias("b"),
(col("a.id") == col("b.id")),
"left"
).select(
col("a.*"),
col("b.designation").alias("col2"),
lit(0).alias("pre_col3"),
lit("").alias("pre_col4"),
lit("").alias("pre_col5"),
lit("").alias("pre_col6")
)
print("Result for df_t1:")
result_table_01.show()
result_table_02 = df_t2.alias("a").join(
df_t2.alias("b"),
(col("a.id") == col("b.id")),
"left"
).select(
col("a.*"),
col("b.designation").alias("col2"),
lit(0).alias("pre_col3"),
lit("").alias("pre_col4"),
lit("").alias("pre_col5"),
lit("").alias("pre_col6")
)
print("Result for df_t2:")
result_table_02.show()
```

In the above code I have imported the below functions:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, concat
```

[image]

And the Below is the code for DELTA table(Parquet) and SQL syntax:

```
output_path_t1_delta = "abfss://folder1@storagejuly26.dfs.core.windows.net/CRC/t1_delta"
df_t1.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("default.tbl1")
output_path_t2_delta = "abfss://folder1@storagejuly26.dfs.core.windows.net/CRC/t2_delta"
df_t2.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("default.df_t2")
spark.sql("""
CREATE  OR  REPLACE  TABLE  default.new_tbl AS
SELECT
a.*,
COALESCE(b.designation, 0) AS col2,
b.pre_col3,
b.pre_col4,
b.pre_col5,
b.pre_col6
FROM
default.tbl1 a -- Delta table for df_t1
LEFT  JOIN (
SELECT  DISTINCT
b.id,
b.designation,
0  AS pre_col3,
''  AS pre_col4,
''  AS pre_col5,
''  AS pre_col6
FROM
default.df_t2 b -- Delta table for df_t2
LEFT  JOIN
default.df_t2 c -- Delta table for df_t2 again (not sure if you need the self-join)
ON b.id  = c.id
) b ON a.id  = b.id
""")
result_table = spark.sql("SELECT  *  FROM  default.new_tbl")
print("Result of the left join:")
result_table.show()
```